# Create AWS Resource Group where Tags do not equal some value

Tags: amazon-web-services, grouping, tagging

I'm trying to create an [AWS Resource Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/resource-groups.html) that helps me locate non-standard resources. In my case, that's one of these two options:

- Resources missing an `Environment` tag
- Resources with a non-standard `Environment` tag value (e.g. `Environment != Production AND Environment != Development`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to find the resources missing a tag. Use the [Tag Editor](https://resources.console.aws.amazon.com/r/tags) to find the resources that are not missing an `Environment` tag.

[image]

Then click on `View as resource group`, give a name to the group and save.

[image]

Comment: Works for missing items, thanks! Any idea how to find ones based on not equal tags e.g. `Environment != prod`?

Comment: Not equal tags is not supported as far as I know. You can find untagged resources and tags with empty values.